# Cisco RV325 VPN to Remote Site with Multiple VLANs

Tags: cisco, router, vlan, vpn

We've been running a VPN over two Cisco RV325's successfully using the following mapping:

```
Site1: IPS="NAME=g2gips0&WEBNAME=Site2&LSUBNET=10.10.0.0&LMASK=255.255.255.0&RG_IP=71.XXX.XXX.6&RNET_T=1&RSUBNET=10.10.10.0&RMASK=255.255.255.0 

Site2: IPS="NAME=g2gips0&WEBNAME=Site1&LSUBNET=10.10.10.0&LMASK=255.255.255.0&&RG_IP=97.XXX.XXX.234&RNET_T=1&RSUBNET=10.10.0.0&RMASK=255.255.255.0&
```

Site 2 recently created a separate 10.10.70.0/24 VLAN to isolate test devices away from PC's and such.  The Site 2 router handles traffic between 10.10.10.0 and 10.10.70.0 fine, but Site 1 can't communicate with anything on 10.10.70.0.  I tried adding

```
Site2: IPS="NAME=g2gips2&WEBNAME=Site1_70&LSUBNET=10.10.70.0&LMASK=255.255.255.0&&RG_IP=97.XXX.XXX.234&RNET_T=1&RSUBNET=10.10.0.0&RMASK=255.255.255.0& <<--not allowed
```

But the Site 2 router complains about having two remote groups with the same subnet/mask.

I've tried other tricks like creating a 10.10.70.0/24 VLAN on Site 1 and mapping it to Site 2's, trying to use IP ranges instead of subnet/masks, and mapping 10.10.0.0/24 to 10.10.0.0/16 with static routes, but all of these make me unable to even talk to the 10.10.10.0 network.

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I'm a bit new to this part of network management, so any guidance would be much appreciated.

SITE1:

```
####sysconfig####

[SYSTEM]
HOSTNAME=XXXXX
DOMAINNAME=XXXXX.com
DOMAINCHANGE=1

LAN=10.10.0.1
LANMASK=255.255.255.0
LANMAC=4C776DEBB510
LANINTERFACE=eth0
BRINTERFACE=br0

WAN_NUMBER=0

[WAN1]
WANTYPE=WAN
OLDWANTYPE=WAN
WAN=97.XXX.XXX.234
WANMASK=255.255.255.252
WANMAC=DEADBEEF
WANINTERFACE=eth1
AUTOMTU=1
MTU=1500
GATEWAY=97.XXX.XXX.233
PPTPSERVER=0.0.0.0
USERSPECIALDNS=YES
DNS1=75.XXX.XXX.1
DNS2=75.XXX.XXX.2
DNS3=0.0.0.0
USERPPPOEDNS=NO
PPPOEDNS1=0.0.0.0
PPPOEDNS2=0.0.0.0
PPPOEDNS3=0.0.0.0
PPPOEDNS4=0.0.0.0
MACCLONE=DEADBEEF
WANCONNECTION=1
DMZHOST=0.0.1.0
UPSTREAMBW=10000
DOWNSTREAMBW=10000
INTERNALLANIP1=0.0.0.0:0
INTERNALLANIP2=0.0.0.0:0
INTERNALLANIP3=0.0.0.0:0
INTERNALLANIP4=0.0.0.0:0
INTERNALLANIP5=0.0.0.0:0
WAN_V6=::
PREFIXLENGTH=64
AUTOMTU_V6=1
MTU_V6=1500
GATEWAY_V6=::
USERSPECIALDNS_V6=NO
DNS1_V6=::
DNS2_V6=::
WANCONNECTION_V6=0
DMZTYPE_V6=SUBNET
DMZ_RANGE_START=::
DMZ_RANGE_END=::
LANPREFIX_V6=::
LANPREFIXLEN_V6=64
PPPOE_SHARE=2
DHCPPD=YES
DHCPPD_TYPE=3
REMOTE_V4=192.88.99.1
REMOTE_V4_MASK=0
REMOTE_V6=::
6IN4_V6=::
6IN4_REMOTE_V4=0.0.0.0
6RD_PREFIX=32
6RD_V4=0.0.0.0
6RD_V6=::
6RD_MODE=0
ALIAS=0


[SMARTLINK]
PRIMARY=WAN1

[ISP1]
WAN=97.XXX.XXX.234
WANMASK=255.255.255.252
MTU=1500
GATEWAY=97.XXX.XXX.233
DNS1=75.XXX.XXX.1
DNS2=75.XXX.XXX.2
DNS3=0.0.0.0
INTERFACE=eth1
STATE=1
NSDOK=1
LINKUP=1
COD_WAN=0.0.0.0
COD_WANMASK=0.0.0.0
COD_GATEWAY=0.0.0.0
PID=0
WAN_V6=::
GATEWAY_V6=::
DNS1_V6=::
DNS2_V6=::
INTERFACE_V6=eth1
STATE_V6=1
LANPREFIX_V6=::
LANPREFIXLEN_V6=64
REMOTE_V4_MASK=0
6RD_PREFIX=32
6RD_V4=0.0.0.0
6RD_V6=::
DHCP_GATEWAY_V6=::
RA_GATEWAY_V6=::

[DHCP]
SERVER=YES
GATEWAY=10.10.0.1
MASK=255.255.255.0
TIMEOUT=86400
WINSERVER=0.0.0.0
WINSERVER2=0.0.0.0
RANGE=10.10.0.100:10.10.0.149
DNS1=0.0.0.0
DNS2=0.0.0.0
STYPE=1
PERPAGENUM=50

[DHCP_SUBNET1]
ENABLED=YES
SERVERIP=10.10.0.1
MASK=255.255.255.0
RANGE=10.10.0.100:10.10.0.149
MATCH_CRITERIA=1
MAC_NUMBER=0
VLAN_NUMBER=0

[DHCP1]
CLIENT=YES

[PORT_FORWARDING]
ID="IP=10.10.0.1&WAN=0&ENABLED=0&ALL=1:65535&ID=1&PROTOCOL=0&START=1&END=65535&NAME=All Traffic"
NUMBER=1
PERPAGENUM=5

[PORT_FORWARDING_CHANGE_PORT]
PORT=10443

[PORT_FWD_LIST]
NUMBER=0

[ACCESS_LIST]
ID="GROUPNAME=&SGROUP=&DGROUP=&ACTION=YES&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=LAN&STYPE=1&DTYPE=1&FSRC=0.0.0.0&TSRC=255.255.255.255&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES&S_NAME=All Traffic&RULENAME="
ID="GROUPNAME=&SGROUP=&DGROUP=&ACTION=YES&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=LAN&STYPE=3&DTYPE=3&FSRC=172.31.0.1&TSRC=172.31.0.254&FDEST=10.10.0.1&TDEST=10.10.10.254&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=NO&S_NAME=All Traffic&RULENAME="
ID="GROUPNAME=&SGROUP=&DGROUP=&ACTION=NO&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=ANY&STYPE=2&DTYPE=1&FSRC=10.10.0.148&TSRC=10.10.0.148&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=NO&S_NAME=All Traffic&RULENAME="
ID="GROUPNAME=&SGROUP=&DGROUP=&ACTION=NO&ID=22&PROTOCOL=TCP&SDPORT=22&EDPORT=22&LOG=NO&IF=LAN&STYPE=3&DTYPE=1&FSRC=192.168.2.1&TSRC=192.168.2.255&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES&S_NAME=SSH&RULENAME="
ID="GROUPNAME=&SGROUP=&DGROUP=&ACTION=NO&ID=22&PROTOCOL=TCP&SDPORT=22&EDPORT=22&LOG=NO&IF=LAN&STYPE=3&DTYPE=1&FSRC=192.168.86.1&TSRC=192.168.86.255&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES&S_NAME=SSH&RULENAME="
ID="GROUPNAME=&SGROUP=&DGROUP=&ACTION=NO&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=YES&IF=LAN&STYPE=3&DTYPE=3&FSRC=192.168.86.1&TSRC=192.168.86.255&FDEST=10.10.0.1&TDEST=10.10.0.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES&S_NAME=All Traffic&RULENAME="
ID="GROUPNAME=&SGROUP=&DGROUP=&ACTION=NO&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=YES&IF=LAN&STYPE=3&DTYPE=3&FSRC=192.168.2.1&TSRC=192.168.2.255&FDEST=10.10.0.1&TDEST=10.10.0.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES&S_NAME=All Traffic&RULENAME="
NUMBER=7
PERPAGE=2
FWRULEEDITNO=0
FWRULECOUNT=0
FWLINEPERPAGE=25
FWTPAGE=1
FWCURRPAGE=1
DELETEFWRULE=0

[ACCESS_RULE]
ID="GROUPNAME=&SGROUP=&DGROUP=&ACTION=YES&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=LAN&STYPE=1&DTYPE=1&FSRC=0.0.0.0&TSRC=255.255.255.255&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES&S_NAME=All Traffic&RULENAME="
ID="GROUPNAME=&SGROUP=&DGROUP=&ACTION=YES&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=LAN&STYPE=3&DTYPE=3&FSRC=172.31.0.1&TSRC=172.31.0.254&FDEST=10.10.0.1&TDEST=10.10.10.254&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=NO&S_NAME=All Traffic&RULENAME="
ID="GROUPNAME=&SGROUP=&DGROUP=&ACTION=NO&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=ANY&STYPE=2&DTYPE=1&FSRC=10.10.0.148&TSRC=10.10.0.148&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=NO&S_NAME=All Traffic&RULENAME="
ID="GROUPNAME=&SGROUP=&DGROUP=&ACTION=NO&ID=22&PROTOCOL=TCP&SDPORT=22&EDPORT=22&LOG=NO&IF=LAN&STYPE=3&DTYPE=1&FSRC=192.168.2.1&TSRC=192.168.2.255&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES&S_NAME=SSH&RULENAME="
ID="GROUPNAME=&SGROUP=&DGROUP=&ACTION=NO&ID=22&PROTOCOL=TCP&SDPORT=22&EDPORT=22&LOG=NO&IF=LAN&STYPE=3&DTYPE=1&FSRC=192.168.86.1&TSRC=192.168.86.255&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES&S_NAME=SSH&RULENAME="
ID="GROUPNAME=&SGROUP=&DGROUP=&ACTION=NO&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=YES&IF=LAN&STYPE=3&DTYPE=3&FSRC=192.168.86.1&TSRC=192.168.86.255&FDEST=10.10.0.1&TDEST=10.10.0.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES&S_NAME=All Traffic&RULENAME="
ID="GROUPNAME=&SGROUP=&DGROUP=&ACTION=NO&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=YES&IF=LAN&STYPE=3&DTYPE=3&FSRC=192.168.2.1&TSRC=192.168.2.255&FDEST=10.10.0.1&TDEST=10.10.0.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES&S_NAME=All Traffic&RULENAME="
NUMBER=7

[ACCESS_WAN]
ID="ACTION=YES&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=DMZ&STYPE=1&FSRC=0.0.0.0&TSRC=255.255.255.255&DTYPE=1&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=NO&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=DMZ&STYPE=1&FSRC=0.0.0.0&TSRC=255.255.255.255&DTYPE=3&FDEST=10.10.0.0&TDEST=10.10.0.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=NO&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=WAN1&STYPE=1&FSRC=0.0.0.0&TSRC=255.255.255.255&DTYPE=1&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=YES&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=WAN1&STYPE=1&FSRC=0.0.0.0&TSRC=255.255.255.255&DTYPE=3&FDEST=97.XXX.XXX.104&TDEST=97.XXX.XXX.111&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=NO&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=USB2&STYPE=1&FSRC=0.0.0.0&TSRC=255.255.255.255&DTYPE=1&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=NO&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=USB1&STYPE=1&FSRC=0.0.0.0&TSRC=255.255.255.255&DTYPE=1&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=YES&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=LAN&STYPE=1&FSRC=0.0.0.0&TSRC=255.255.255.255&DTYPE=1&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
NUMBER=7

[ACCESS_DMZ]
ID="ACTION=NO&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=WAN1&STYPE=1&FSRC=0.0.0.0&TSRC=255.255.255.255&DTYPE=1&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=YES&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=LAN&STYPE=1&FSRC=0.0.0.0&TSRC=255.255.255.255&DTYPE=1&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
NUMBER=2

[ACCESS_LIST_V6]
NUMBER=0
PERPAGE=1
FWRULEEDITNO=0
FWRULECOUNT=0
FWLINEPERPAGE=5
FWTPAGE=1
FWCURRPAGE=1
DELETEFWRULE=0

[ACCESS_RULE_V6]
NUMBER=0

[ACCESS_WAN_V6]
ID="ACTION=NO&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=DMZ&STYPE=1&SRC=::&SRC_LN=0&DTYPE=1&DEST=::&DEST_LN=0&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=NO&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=WAN1&STYPE=1&SRC=::&SRC_LN=0&DTYPE=1&DEST=::&DEST_LN=0&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=NO&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=USB2&STYPE=1&SRC=::&SRC_LN=0&DTYPE=1&DEST=::&DEST_LN=0&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=NO&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=USB1&STYPE=1&SRC=::&SRC_LN=0&DTYPE=1&DEST=::&DEST_LN=0&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=YES&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=LAN&STYPE=1&SRC=::&SRC_LN=0&DTYPE=1&DEST=::&DEST_LN=0&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
NUMBER=5

[ACCESS_DMZ_V6]
NUMBER=0
DefaultFlag=0

[STATIC_IP]
(santized)
NUMBER=47
BLOCK_MAC_WRONG_IP=NO
BLOCK_MAC_NOT_LIST=NO
PERPAGENUM=50
STATUS=0

[STATIC_ROUTE]
ID="IF=WAN1&DST=10.10.10.0&MASK=255.255.255.0&GATE=71.XXX.XXX.6&METR=5"
NUMBER=1
PERPAGENUM=5

[STATIC_ROUTE_V6]
NUMBER=0
PERPAGENUM=5


[VLAN_DEFAULT]
ID="VID=4001&ENABLED=YES&DIR=0&CPU=1&DHCP1_ENABLED=YES&DHCP1_INDEX=1&DHCP2_ENABLED=YES&DHCP2_INDEX=2&DHCP3_ENABLED=YES&DHCP3_INDEX=3&DHCP4_ENABLED=YES&DHCP4_INDEX=4&MEMBER=255"
ID="VID=4051&ENABLED=YES&DIR=0&CPU=1&DHCP1_ENABLED=YES&DHCP1_INDEX=1&DHCP2_ENABLED=YES&DHCP2_INDEX=2&DHCP3_ENABLED=YES&DHCP3_INDEX=3&DHCP4_ENABLED=YES&DHCP4_INDEX=4&MEMBER=255"
ID="VID=4052&ENABLED=NO&DIR=0&CPU=1&DHCP1_ENABLED=NO&DHCP1_INDEX=0&DHCP2_ENABLED=NO&DHCP2_INDEX=0&DHCP3_ENABLED=NO&DHCP3_INDEX=0&DHCP4_ENABLED=NO&DHCP4_INDEX=0&&MEMBER=0"
ID="VID=4053&ENABLED=NO&DIR=0&CPU=1&DHCP1_ENABLED=NO&DHCP1_INDEX=0&DHCP2_ENABLED=NO&DHCP2_INDEX=0&DHCP3_ENABLED=NO&DHCP3_INDEX=0&DHCP4_ENABLED=NO&DHCP4_INDEX=0&&MEMBER=0"
ID="VID=4054&ENABLED=NO&DIR=0&CPU=1&DHCP1_ENABLED=NO&DHCP1_INDEX=0&DHCP2_ENABLED=NO&DHCP2_INDEX=0&DHCP3_ENABLED=NO&DHCP3_INDEX=0&DHCP4_ENABLED=NO&DHCP4_INDEX=0&&MEMBER=0"
ID="VID=4055&ENABLED=NO&DIR=0&CPU=1&DHCP1_ENABLED=NO&DHCP1_INDEX=0&DHCP2_ENABLED=NO&DHCP2_INDEX=0&DHCP3_ENABLED=NO&DHCP3_INDEX=0&DHCP4_ENABLED=NO&DHCP4_INDEX=0&&MEMBER=0"
ID="VID=4056&ENABLED=NO&DIR=0&CPU=1&DHCP1_ENABLED=NO&DHCP1_INDEX=0&DHCP2_ENABLED=NO&DHCP2_INDEX=0&DHCP3_ENABLED=NO&DHCP3_INDEX=0&DHCP4_ENABLED=NO&DHCP4_INDEX=0&&MEMBER=0"
ID="VID=4057&ENABLED=NO&DIR=0&CPU=1&DHCP1_ENABLED=NO&DHCP1_INDEX=0&DHCP2_ENABLED=NO&DHCP2_INDEX=0&DHCP3_ENABLED=NO&DHCP3_INDEX=0&DHCP4_ENABLED=NO&DHCP4_INDEX=0&&MEMBER=0"
ID="VID=4058&ENABLED=NO&DIR=0&CPU=1&DHCP1_ENABLED=NO&DHCP1_INDEX=0&DHCP2_ENABLED=NO&DHCP2_INDEX=0&DHCP3_ENABLED=NO&DHCP3_INDEX=0&DHCP4_ENABLED=NO&DHCP4_INDEX=0&&MEMBER=0"
ID="VID=4081&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=32768"
ID="VID=4082&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=16384"
ID="VID=4083&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=8192"
ID="VID=4084&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=4096"
ID="VID=4085&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=2048"
ID="VID=4086&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=1024"
ID="VID=4087&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=512"
ID="VID=4088&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=256"
NUMBER=17
ENABLED_NUMBER=10

[VLAN_TAG]
ENABLED=NO
NUMBER=9
ENABLED_NUMBER=9

[VLAN_TAG_LAN]
ID="VID=4001&ENABLED=YES&DIR=0&CPU=1&MEMBER=255"
NUMBER=1

[VLAN_TAG_WAN]
ID="VID=4081&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=32768"
ID="VID=4082&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=16384"
ID="VID=4083&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=8192"
ID="VID=4084&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=4096"
ID="VID=4085&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=2048"
ID="VID=4086&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=1024"
ID="VID=4087&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=512"
ID="VID=4088&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=256"
NUMBER=8

[VLAN_SUBNET]
ID="ENABLED=YES&SUBNET_INDEX=0&DHCP_ENABLED=YES&DHCP_INDEX=1&VID=4001"
NUMBER=1
ENABLED_NUMBER=1


[IPSEC_G2G]
IPS="NAME=g2gips0&WEBNAME=Test Center&ENABLED=1&PkStrength=1&KEY_EXG_T=1&LG_T=1&LG_IF=1&LIKE_ID_T=0&LIKE_ID_NAME=&LocalCA=&LNET_T=1&LSUBNET=10.10.0.0&LMASK=255.255.255.0&RG_N=1&RG_T=0&RIKE_ID_T=0&RG_IP=71.41.66.6&RNET_T=1&RSUBNET=10.10.10.0&RMASK=255.255.255.0&RemoteCA=&KEYM=2&PH1_DH=1&PH1_ENC=5&PH1_AUTH=2&PH1_TIME=28800&PH2_DH=1&PH2_ENC=5&PH2_AUTH=2&PH2_TIME=3600&PH2_HASH=0&ADV=1&POLICY=22&PSK=xEbKDd6zzsijp4mt5wiT8zyinFupjisr&DPD_PERIOD=10&DPD_ACT=1&DPD_RETRY=3&UPDN=&XAUTH=&XAUTH_TYPE=0&XAUTH_SERVER_INDEX=&USERNAME=&PASSWORD=&HB_Enable=0&HB_RemoteHost=0.0.0.0&HB_Interval=10&HB_RetryCount=3&TBK=1&RG_DNSBK=&LG_IFBK=1&TBKT=30&LG_BKmode=2&SDS1=&SDS2=&SDN1=&SDN2=&SDN3=&SDN4="
NUMBER=1
LINEPERPAGE=5
MAXNUM=50
PERPAGENUM=5

[IPSEC_GRP]
IPS="NAME=grpips0&WEBNAME=Easy VPN&ENABLED=1&PkStrength=1&KEY_EXG_T=1&LG_T=2&LG_IF=1&LIKE_ID_T=0&LIKE_ID_NAME=&LNET_T=1&LSUBNET=10.10.0.0&LMASK=255.255.255.0&RG_N=7&RG_T=6&RIKE_ID_T=10&RIKE_ID_NAME=gooee_DTSP&RG_IP=0&RNET_T=0&RSUBNET=0&RMASK=0&KEYM=2&PH1_DH=2&PH1_ENC=5&PH1_AUTH=2&PH1_TIME=86400&PH2_DH=2&PH2_ENC=5&PH2_AUTH=1&PH2_TIME=86400&PH2_HASH=0&ADV=1&POLICY=7381315&PSK=t0ps3cr3t!!&DPD_PERIOD=10&DPD_ACT=1&DPD_RETRY=3&UPDN=&XAUTH=1&XAUTH_TYPE=1&XAUTH_SERVER_INDEX=0&USERNAME=&PASSWORD=&MODECFG=1&MODECFGID=4&TUNNELMODE=1"
NUMBER=1
LINEPERPAGE=5
MAXNUM=2


[MULTIPLE_SUBNET]
ENABLED=YES
ID="VID=1&IP=10.10.0.1&NETMASK=255.255.255.0&IS_ROUTE=1&DHCP_MODE=1&RELAY=0.0.0.0&TIME=1440&RANGES=10.10.0.10&RANGEE=10.10.0.229&DNS1=75.XXX.XXX.1&DNS2=75.XXX.XXX.2&WINS=0.0.0.0&TFTPN=&TFTPP=0.0.0.0&TFTPF=&CID=Null&DNSSERVER=1"
ID="VID=25&IP=192.168.2.1&NETMASK=255.255.255.0&IS_ROUTE=1&DHCP_MODE=1&RELAY=0.0.0.0&TIME=1440&RANGES=192.168.2.100&RANGEE=192.168.2.149&DNS1=75.XXX.XXX.1&DNS2=75.XXX.XXX.2&WINS=0.0.0.0&TFTPN=&TFTPP=0.0.0.0&TFTPF=&CID=Null&DNSSERVER=1"
ID="VID=100&IP=192.168.3.1&NETMASK=255.255.255.0&IS_ROUTE=1&DHCP_MODE=1&RELAY=0.0.0.0&TIME=1440&RANGES=192.168.3.100&RANGEE=192.168.3.149&DNS1=0.0.0.0&DNS2=0.0.0.0&WINS=0.0.0.0&TFTPN=&TFTPP=0.0.0.0&TFTPF=&CID=Null&DNSSERVER=1"
NUMBER=3


[VLAN]
ENABLE=YES
ID="VID=1&DESC=Default&P1=2&P2=0&P3=0&P4=0&P5=0&P6=0&P7=0&P8=0&P9=0&P10=0&P11=0&P12=0&P13=0&P14=0&P15=0&P16=0&bonjour=1&VLAN_ROUTE=1&DEVICE_M=1"
ID="VID=25&DESC=Guest&P1=0&P2=2&P3=2&P4=2&P5=2&P6=2&P7=2&P8=2&P9=2&P10=2&P11=2&P12=2&P13=2&P14=2&P15=0&P16=0&bonjour=1&VLAN_ROUTE=0&DEVICE_M=0"
ID="VID=100&DESC=Voice&P1=2&P2=1&P3=1&P4=1&P5=1&P6=1&P7=1&P8=1&P9=1&P10=1&P11=1&P12=1&P13=1&P14=1&P15=0&P16=0&bonjour=1&VLAN_ROUTE=0&DEVICE_M=0"
ID="VID=20&DESC=TCVPN&P1=1&P2=1&P3=1&P4=1&P5=1&P6=1&P7=1&P8=1&P9=1&P10=1&P11=1&P12=1&P13=1&P14=1&P15=0&P16=0&bonjour=1&VLAN_ROUTE=1&DEVICE_M=1"
NUMBER=4
PERPAGENUM_B=5
PERPAGENUM_M=5

[VLAN_MEMBERSHIP]
ENABLE=NO
NUMBER=0
LINEPERPAGE=5

[MULTIPLE_VLAN_SUBNET]
NUMBER=0


####end####
```

Site 2:

```
####sysconfig####

[SYSTEM]
HOSTNAME=XXXXX
DOMAINNAME=XXXXX.com
DOMAINCHANGE=1
LAN=10.10.10.1
LANMASK=255.255.255.0
LANMAC=4C776DEBB510
LANINTERFACE=eth0
BRINTERFACE=br0
WAN_NUMBER=0

[WAN1]
WANTYPE=WAN
OLDWANTYPE=WAN
WAN=71.XXX.XXX.6
WANMASK=255.255.255.252
WANMAC=DEADBEEF
WANINTERFACE=eth1
AUTOMTU=1
MTU=1500
GATEWAY=71.XXX.XXX.5
PPTPSERVER=0.0.0.0
USERSPECIALDNS=NO
DNS1=75.XXX.XXX.1
DNS2=75.XXX.XXX.2
DNS3=0.0.0.0
USERPPPOEDNS=NO
PPPOEDNS1=0.0.0.0
PPPOEDNS2=0.0.0.0
PPPOEDNS3=0.0.0.0
PPPOEDNS4=0.0.0.0
MACCLONE=BEEFCAFE
WANCONNECTION=1
DMZHOST=0.0.1.0
UPSTREAMBW=10000
DOWNSTREAMBW=10000
INTERNALLANIP1=0.0.0.0:0
INTERNALLANIP2=0.0.0.0:0
INTERNALLANIP3=0.0.0.0:0
INTERNALLANIP4=0.0.0.0:0
INTERNALLANIP5=0.0.0.0:0
WAN_V6=::
PREFIXLENGTH=64
AUTOMTU_V6=1
MTU_V6=1500
GATEWAY_V6=::
USERSPECIALDNS_V6=NO
DNS1_V6=::
DNS2_V6=::
WANCONNECTION_V6=0
DMZTYPE_V6=SUBNET
DMZ_RANGE_START=::
DMZ_RANGE_END=::
LANPREFIX_V6=::
LANPREFIXLEN_V6=64
PPPOE_SHARE=2
DHCPPD=YES
DHCPPD_TYPE=3
REMOTE_V4=192.88.99.1
REMOTE_V4_MASK=0
REMOTE_V6=::
6IN4_V6=::
6IN4_REMOTE_V4=0.0.0.0
6RD_PREFIX=32
6RD_V4=0.0.0.0
6RD_V6=::
6RD_MODE=0
ALIAS=0


[SMARTLINK]
PRIMARY=WAN1

[ISP1]
WAN=71.XXX.XXX.6
WANMASK=255.255.255.252
MTU=1500
GATEWAY=71.XXX.XXX.5
DNS1=75.XXX.XXX.1
DNS2=75.XXX.XXX.2
DNS3=0.0.0.0
INTERFACE=eth1
STATE=1
NSDOK=1
LINKUP=0
COD_WAN=0.0.0.0
COD_WANMASK=0.0.0.0
COD_GATEWAY=0.0.0.0
PID=0
WAN_V6=::
GATEWAY_V6=::
DNS1_V6=::
DNS2_V6=::
INTERFACE_V6=eth1
STATE_V6=1
LANPREFIX_V6=::
LANPREFIXLEN_V6=64
REMOTE_V4_MASK=0
6RD_PREFIX=32
6RD_V4=0.0.0.0
6RD_V6=::
DHCP_GATEWAY_V6=::
RA_GATEWAY_V6=::

[DHCP]
SERVER=YES
GATEWAY=10.10.10.1
MASK=255.255.255.0
TIMEOUT=86400
WINSERVER=0.0.0.0
WINSERVER2=0.0.0.0
RANGE=10.10.10.100:10.10.10.149
DNS1=0.0.0.0
DNS2=0.0.0.0
STYPE=1
PERPAGENUM=50

[DHCP_SUBNET1]
ENABLED=YES
SERVERIP=10.10.10.1
MASK=255.255.255.0
RANGE=10.10.10.100:10.10.10.149
MATCH_CRITERIA=1
MAC_NUMBER=0
VLAN_NUMBER=0

[DHCP1]
CLIENT=YES

[PORT_FORWARDING]
NUMBER=0
PERPAGENUM=5

[PORT_FORWARDING_CHANGE_PORT]
PORT=443

[PORT_FWD_LIST]
NUMBER=0

[ACCESS_LIST]
NUMBER=0
PERPAGE=2
FWRULEEDITNO=0
FWRULECOUNT=0
FWLINEPERPAGE=25
FWTPAGE=1
FWCURRPAGE=1
DELETEFWRULE=0

[ACCESS_RULE]
NUMBER=0

[ACCESS_WAN]
ID="ACTION=NO&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=WAN2&STYPE=1&FSRC=0.0.0.0&TSRC=255.255.255.255&DTYPE=1&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=NO&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=WAN1&STYPE=1&FSRC=0.0.0.0&TSRC=255.255.255.255&DTYPE=1&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=NO&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=USB2&STYPE=1&FSRC=0.0.0.0&TSRC=255.255.255.255&DTYPE=1&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=NO&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=USB1&STYPE=1&FSRC=0.0.0.0&TSRC=255.255.255.255&DTYPE=1&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=YES&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=LAN&STYPE=1&FSRC=0.0.0.0&TSRC=255.255.255.255&DTYPE=1&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
NUMBER=5

[ACCESS_DMZ]
ID="ACTION=NO&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=WAN1&STYPE=1&FSRC=0.0.0.0&TSRC=255.255.255.255&DTYPE=1&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=YES&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=LAN&STYPE=1&FSRC=0.0.0.0&TSRC=255.255.255.255&DTYPE=1&FDEST=0.0.0.0&TDEST=255.255.255.255&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
NUMBER=2

[ACCESS_LIST_V6]
NUMBER=0
PERPAGE=1
FWRULEEDITNO=0
FWRULECOUNT=0
FWLINEPERPAGE=5
FWTPAGE=1
FWCURRPAGE=1
DELETEFWRULE=0

[ACCESS_RULE_V6]
NUMBER=0

[ACCESS_WAN_V6]
ID="ACTION=NO&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=WAN2&STYPE=1&SRC=::&SRC_LN=0&DTYPE=1&DEST=::&DEST_LN=0&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=NO&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=WAN1&STYPE=1&SRC=::&SRC_LN=0&DTYPE=1&DEST=::&DEST_LN=0&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=NO&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=USB2&STYPE=1&SRC=::&SRC_LN=0&DTYPE=1&DEST=::&DEST_LN=0&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=NO&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=USB1&STYPE=1&SRC=::&SRC_LN=0&DTYPE=1&DEST=::&DEST_LN=0&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
ID="ACTION=YES&NAME=Default&ID=1&PROTOCOL=ALL&SDPORT=1&EDPORT=65535&LOG=NO&IF=LAN&STYPE=1&SRC=::&SRC_LN=0&DTYPE=1&DEST=::&DEST_LN=0&TIMECON=NO&START=&STOP=&DAYS=&DALL=&EN=YES"
NUMBER=5

[ACCESS_DMZ_V6]
NUMBER=0
DefaultFlag=0

[STATIC_IP]
(sanitized)
NUMBER=80
BLOCK_MAC_WRONG_IP=NO
BLOCK_MAC_NOT_LIST=NO
PERPAGENUM=50
STATUS=0

[STATIC_ROUTE]
ID="IF=WAN1&DST=10.10.0.0&MASK=255.255.255.0&GATE=97.XXX.XXX.234&METR=5"
NUMBER=1
PERPAGENUM=5

[STATIC_ROUTE_V6]
NUMBER=0
PERPAGENUM=5


[VLAN_DEFAULT]
ID="VID=4001&ENABLED=YES&DIR=0&CPU=1&DHCP1_ENABLED=YES&DHCP1_INDEX=1&DHCP2_ENABLED=YES&DHCP2_INDEX=2&DHCP3_ENABLED=YES&DHCP3_INDEX=3&DHCP4_ENABLED=YES&DHCP4_INDEX=4&MEMBER=255"
ID="VID=4051&ENABLED=YES&DIR=0&CPU=1&DHCP1_ENABLED=YES&DHCP1_INDEX=1&DHCP2_ENABLED=YES&DHCP2_INDEX=2&DHCP3_ENABLED=YES&DHCP3_INDEX=3&DHCP4_ENABLED=YES&DHCP4_INDEX=4&MEMBER=255"
ID="VID=4052&ENABLED=NO&DIR=0&CPU=1&DHCP1_ENABLED=NO&DHCP1_INDEX=0&DHCP2_ENABLED=NO&DHCP2_INDEX=0&DHCP3_ENABLED=NO&DHCP3_INDEX=0&DHCP4_ENABLED=NO&DHCP4_INDEX=0&&MEMBER=0"
ID="VID=4053&ENABLED=NO&DIR=0&CPU=1&DHCP1_ENABLED=NO&DHCP1_INDEX=0&DHCP2_ENABLED=NO&DHCP2_INDEX=0&DHCP3_ENABLED=NO&DHCP3_INDEX=0&DHCP4_ENABLED=NO&DHCP4_INDEX=0&&MEMBER=0"
ID="VID=4054&ENABLED=NO&DIR=0&CPU=1&DHCP1_ENABLED=NO&DHCP1_INDEX=0&DHCP2_ENABLED=NO&DHCP2_INDEX=0&DHCP3_ENABLED=NO&DHCP3_INDEX=0&DHCP4_ENABLED=NO&DHCP4_INDEX=0&&MEMBER=0"
ID="VID=4055&ENABLED=NO&DIR=0&CPU=1&DHCP1_ENABLED=NO&DHCP1_INDEX=0&DHCP2_ENABLED=NO&DHCP2_INDEX=0&DHCP3_ENABLED=NO&DHCP3_INDEX=0&DHCP4_ENABLED=NO&DHCP4_INDEX=0&&MEMBER=0"
ID="VID=4056&ENABLED=NO&DIR=0&CPU=1&DHCP1_ENABLED=NO&DHCP1_INDEX=0&DHCP2_ENABLED=NO&DHCP2_INDEX=0&DHCP3_ENABLED=NO&DHCP3_INDEX=0&DHCP4_ENABLED=NO&DHCP4_INDEX=0&&MEMBER=0"
ID="VID=4057&ENABLED=NO&DIR=0&CPU=1&DHCP1_ENABLED=NO&DHCP1_INDEX=0&DHCP2_ENABLED=NO&DHCP2_INDEX=0&DHCP3_ENABLED=NO&DHCP3_INDEX=0&DHCP4_ENABLED=NO&DHCP4_INDEX=0&&MEMBER=0"
ID="VID=4058&ENABLED=NO&DIR=0&CPU=1&DHCP1_ENABLED=NO&DHCP1_INDEX=0&DHCP2_ENABLED=NO&DHCP2_INDEX=0&DHCP3_ENABLED=NO&DHCP3_INDEX=0&DHCP4_ENABLED=NO&DHCP4_INDEX=0&&MEMBER=0"
ID="VID=4081&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=32768"
ID="VID=4082&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=16384"
ID="VID=4083&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=8192"
ID="VID=4084&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=4096"
ID="VID=4085&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=2048"
ID="VID=4086&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=1024"
ID="VID=4087&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=512"
ID="VID=4088&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=256"
NUMBER=17
ENABLED_NUMBER=10

[VLAN_TAG]
ENABLED=NO
NUMBER=9
ENABLED_NUMBER=9

[VLAN_TAG_LAN]
ID="VID=4001&ENABLED=YES&DIR=0&CPU=1&MEMBER=255"
NUMBER=1

[VLAN_TAG_WAN]
ID="VID=4081&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=32768"
ID="VID=4082&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=16384"
ID="VID=4083&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=8192"
ID="VID=4084&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=4096"
ID="VID=4085&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=2048"
ID="VID=4086&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=1024"
ID="VID=4087&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=512"
ID="VID=4088&ENABLED=YES&DIR=1&CPU=1&MEMBER=256"
NUMBER=8

[VLAN_SUBNET]
ID="ENABLED=YES&SUBNET_INDEX=0&DHCP_ENABLED=YES&DHCP_INDEX=1&VID=4001"
NUMBER=1
ENABLED_NUMBER=1


[IPSEC_G2G]
IPS="NAME=g2gips0&WEBNAME=Downtown&ENABLED=1&PkStrength=1&KEY_EXG_T=1&LG_T=1&LG_IF=1&LIKE_ID_T=0&LIKE_ID_NAME=&LocalCA=&LNET_T=1&LSUBNET=10.10.10.0&LMASK=255.255.255.0&RG_N=1&RG_T=0&RIKE_ID_T=0&RG_IP=97.XXX.XXX.234&RNET_T=1&RSUBNET=10.10.0.0&RMASK=255.255.255.0&RemoteCA=&KEYM=2&PH1_DH=1&PH1_ENC=5&PH1_AUTH=2&PH1_TIME=28800&PH2_DH=1&PH2_ENC=5&PH2_AUTH=2&PH2_TIME=3600&PH2_HASH=0&ADV=1&POLICY=22&PSK=xEbKDd6zzsijp4mt5wiT8zyinFupjisr&DPD_PERIOD=10&DPD_ACT=1&DPD_RETRY=3&UPDN=&XAUTH=&XAUTH_TYPE=0&XAUTH_SERVER_INDEX=&USERNAME=&PASSWORD=&HB_Enable=0&HB_RemoteHost=0.0.0.0&HB_Interval=10&HB_RetryCount=3&TBK=1&RG_DNSBK=&LG_(not allowed)IFBK=1&TBKT=30&LG_BKmode=2&SDS1=&SDS2=&SDN1=&SDN2=&SDN3=&SDN4="
NUMBER=1
LINEPERPAGE=5
MAXNUM=50
PERPAGENUM=5

[IPSEC_GRP]
IPS="NAME=grpips0&WEBNAME=Easy VPN&ENABLED=1&PkStrength=1&KEY_EXG_T=1&LG_T=2&LG_IF=1&LIKE_ID_T=0&LIKE_ID_NAME=&LNET_T=1&LSUBNET=10.10.10.0&LMASK=255.255.255.0&RG_N=7&RG_T=6&RIKE_ID_T=10&RIKE_ID_NAME=Test_Centre&RG_IP=0&RNET_T=0&RSUBNET=0&RMASK=0&KEYM=2&PH1_DH=2&PH1_ENC=5&PH1_AUTH=2&PH1_TIME=86400&PH2_DH=2&PH2_ENC=5&PH2_AUTH=1&PH2_TIME=86400&PH2_HASH=0&ADV=1&POLICY=7381315&PSK=t0ps3cr3t!!&DPD_PERIOD=10&DPD_ACT=1&DPD_RETRY=3&UPDN=&XAUTH=1&XAUTH_TYPE=1&XAUTH_SERVER_INDEX=0&USERNAME=&PASSWORD=&MODECFG=1&MODECFGID=4&TUNNELMODE=1"
NUMBER=1
LINEPERPAGE=5
MAXNUM=2


[MULTIPLE_SUBNET]
ENABLED=YES
ID="VID=1&IP=10.10.10.1&NETMASK=255.255.255.0&IS_ROUTE=1&DHCP_MODE=1&RELAY=0.0.0.0&TIME=1440&RANGES=10.10.10.10&RANGEE=10.10.10.249&DNS1=0.0.0.0&DNS2=0.0.0.0&WINS=0.0.0.0&TFTPN=&TFTPP=0.0.0.0&TFTPF=&CID=Null&DNSSERVER=2"
NUMBER=1



[VLAN]
ENABLE=YES
ID="VID=1&DESC=Default&P1=0&P2=0&P3=0&P4=0&P5=0&P6=0&P7=2&P8=0&P9=0&P10=0&P11=0&P12=0&P13=0&P14=2&P15=0&P16=0&bonjour=1&VLAN_ROUTE=1&DEVICE_M=1"
ID="VID=70&DESC=SideOffices&P1=2&P2=2&P3=2&P4=2&P5=2&P6=2&P7=0&P8=2&P9=2&P10=2&P11=2&P12=2&P13=2&P14=0&P15=0&P16=0&bonjour=1&VLAN_ROUTE=1&DEVICE_M=1"
NUMBER=2
PERPAGENUM_B=5
PERPAGENUM_M=25

[VLAN_MEMBERSHIP]
ENABLE=NO
NUMBER=0
LINEPERPAGE=5

[MULTIPLE_VLAN_SUBNET]
NUMBER=0


####end####
```

Comment: You need to edit your question to provide more information. At least start with the router configurations.

Comment: @RonMaupin I've updated my original entry.  Please let me know if you need more.

Comment: What we really want to see is the full (sanitized) router configurations. Simply show the configurations in your terminal application. Obfuscate the public addresses and passwords, then paste the configurations into the question.

Comment: @ron  Those things are pretty big and I didn't see a way to attach files, but I'll paste them in if you really want.

Comment: You actually have a limit of 30,000 characters. Simply paste into the question and use the Preformatted-text option (`{}`). That will create scroll boxes for you.

Comment: @RonMaupin I still had to take a hatchet to each config.exp file to get it w/in 30,000 characters for both.  I hope I gave you enough.  These are configs that don't include any effort to add the 10.10.70.0 subnet at Site2, so you'd have a baseline.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We gave up trying to set up two VPN connections and simply moved the Site2 network to 10.11.x.x.  That let us use /16 netmasks and they all connect.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.